# ORA-01843: not a valid month mentioned the date format a well

Tags: sql

I am using trying to fetch data from Oracle using the TOAD application. 
I have the following code:

```
select * from a
where trunc(a.eff_dt) between trunc(to_date('01/01/2015','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
and trunc(to_date('01/02/2015','MM/DD/YYYY'))
and br_type = 'ASD'
```

However when i submit the code, it does not give any error & only generates a blank output. 
Kindly suggest as i also used without adding the mm/dd/yyyy format in dates as well. 
Thanks.

Comment: There are no records in your data with `br_type = 'ASD'` and dates on the first two days of this year.

Comment: Depending on data type, if time is also stored, you might actually only be asking for January 1 in your query.    Not 100% certain thought because I am not sure of the date data type of eff_dt and haven't used Oracle in quite some time.   Hopefully someone can chime in and correct me if I am wrong...